# Android stylesheeets?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I don't know much about Android, but doesn't [android-stylesheeets](/questions/tagged/android-stylesheeets) have one "e" too many? I'd rather not edit 141 questions by hand, and it already has a tag wiki.

Comment: Aw sheeet, someeeoneee meeesseeed this oneee up.

Comment: I don't see an "eeek!", must not be that important.

Comment: Perhaps add a new tag with proper spelling and make this a synonym of that tag?  Then you'd only need to copy/paste the tag wiki.

Comment: What in the name of god is an Android stylesheet!?

Comment: @OctavianDamiean Nothing, it doesn't exist.  Perhaps you meant "stylesheeet"?

Comment: This is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: Incredible ... 141 questions tagged with a tag that doesn't even make sense because there is no thing like an Android stylesheet.

Comment: @OctavianDamiean Should all of these just be using both [`[android]+[styles]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+styles)? They look like they're referring to [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

Comment: @BilltheLizard Yea, probably. Even though I'm not sure if `[style]` isn't too much of a meta tag. `[android-layout]` is pretty much spot on. It is about Android layouts.

Comment: Nonono, you're all wrong! Now how do people ask about stylesheeets? (just in case someone actually takes this seriously, it's a joke `:P`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went ahead and used [Servy's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186104/android-stylesheeets#comment570703_186104) and made a synonym from [android-stylesheeets](/questions/tagged/android-stylesheeets) to [android-stylesheets](/questions/tagged/android-stylesheets) and then merged the tags.

Comment: And the irony is that neither tag makes any sense. There are no 'style sheets' on android.

Comment: And you lost the wiki. Is there any way to get that back?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII It looks like most of the questions have something to do with the `style` XML attribute.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Damn it. No, I lost the wiki.

Comment: IIRC the wiki was just a copy-paste from the developer's manual so no big loss.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Not to worry, using the data explorer I got it back and added it.

Comment: @Juhana Whew! That's a relief.  I still might have to change this again, but at least the misspelled tag is gone.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII is right. There is no such a thing as a stylesheet. At least it has never been called that way in any official documentation.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Finally got around to correcting this today. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201801/1288

Comment: @OctavianDamiean I went ahead and fixed this one step further. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201801/1288