# Retag [android-stylesheets]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I just ran across a question tagged [android-stylesheets](/questions/tagged/android-stylesheets). Now, I understand what they're talking about, but I've never ever heard it called a stylesheet, either in documentation or informally.

Honestly, I think a combination of [android](/questions/tagged/android)[styles](/questions/tagged/styles) is best for it, but if nothing else, could we at least get a rename to [android-styles](/questions/tagged/android-styles)? There *are* such things as [styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) in android, and that's what [all these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-stylesheets) are referring to.

I noticed this was discussed briefly in the [comments here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186104/212780), but that was mainly about a typo-tag.

Comment: [tag:styles]? If there is any decency left in the world...

Comment: Well it is rather meta, but no worse than themes, layout, templates, etc, and I see those used all the time. As long as it's combined with a "proper" tag to make it clear, I don't see much of a problem. The main point is, Android has no concept of stylesheets, only styles. Renaming it [android-styles] is just fine by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API guide [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) page is the only place I've seen "stylesheet" used in the official documentation, and then only to draw an analogy between styles and cascading stylesheets.  As such, it makes sense to me to shorten the tag to the correct name [android-styles](/questions/tagged/android-styles).  I've created a synonym and merged the questions to the shorter tag.

Comment: Hey look! [Took you long enough...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186104/android-stylesheeets/186107?noredirect=1#comment570715_186107) :P